# Enforce class only once in jar/ear/rar with maven build

Tags: java, maven

In light of a [recent problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40799974/deployment-of-resource-adapter-on-wildfly-wflyjca0046-ij020066) I had, I would like to make sure it does not happen again. Kind of like a regression test for my build system.

I need a way to scan an ear (or other jar style package) to make sure a class is only once in it.

Example:

```
- test.ear
| - lib (folder)
| | - api.jar (zipped file)
|   | - packageName
|     | - ClassName.class
| - connector.rar (zipped file)
  | - api.jar (zipped file)
    | - packageName
      | - ClassName.class
| - ejbs.jar
```

The `pom.xml` of `ejbs.jar` has a `dependency` on the `api` that brings the `api.jar` to the `lib` folder. The `pom.xml` of the `connector.rar` also has a dependency on the `api` that brings the `api.jar` to the `connector.rar` file, so while the reference to the same dependency, it still causes the above result.

As I have a maven build I'm looking for a way that integrates well there (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

There's this enforcer rule you can use. Have a look at http://www.mojohaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/banDuplicateClasses.html

Comment: On first look: this doesn't do what I need as it assumes each dependency is only once present. My problem is that I have an EAR that contains a RAR and a lib folder. The RAR does contain its own libs, so I need to make sure that I don't have a class in a jar in the lib folder that I also have in the rar. I'll edit my question to make it more clear.